# UITableView getting clipped by 1 pixel on the right

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a custom cell which have a background image. But the tableview is getting clipped by 1 pixel on the right. No matter what I tried, the image wont occupy the whole width.

So far I tried the below settings :

[image]

Also, this :

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

What might be the issue?

Test Image :

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the background image you're using is the full width of the cell? Probably 640px if you're using a retina device.

Comment: yes. The image that I'm adding have a width  > 650px.

Answer (score 1):

My UITableView was starting from (-1,0)
After setting a width constraint, the tableview occupied the whole width.
Thanks.